# Does the engine's thrust not contribute to the lift?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, lift

Does the engine's thrust not contribute to the lift?

Here are my thoughts:

There are two types of aircraft resistance, one is the resistance created to create lift, referred to as lift resistance, and the other is other resistance.
 Why is there lift resistance?

### Because the wing has an angle of attack, there will be an area in the direction of the speed of the wing, so there will be lift resistance.

[image]

The engine's thrust balances lift resistance and other resistances to make the aircraft fly.
 So does thrust contribute only to overcoming resistance and not contribute to lift?

Because drag contains lift resistance, and overcoming lift resistance is generating lift.  If the lift resistance is not overcome, the aircraft cannot move and the wings cannot generate lift.  Moreover, even if the aircraft is moving, if there is no engine thrust to overcome the lift resistance, then the inertia overcomes the lift resistance, so the speed of the aircraft will continue to decrease and the lift will continue to decrease.  So to generate lift, there must be engine thrust to overcome the lift resistance.

The glider does not have an engine, but in fact the glider uses the component of gravity as the thrust to overcome the lift resistance, thereby generating lift.  So, in order to generate lift, the glider had to lose altitude.

### The wing is similar to a inclined plane.  We all know that there must be a thrust object to be stationary on the inclined plane.  It is wrong to say that the thrust does not contribute to the stationary object on the inclined plane.

[image]

Why is the push-to-weight ratio smaller than 1?
 Because the wing is an inclined plane, we all know that the smaller the angle θ, the smaller the force F that keeps the object stationary on the inclined plane.  The same is true for the wing. The angle of attack of the wing is generally small, so the ratio of the aircraft's thrust-to-weight ratio is less than 1.  Of course, this θ angle is not the angle of attack of the wing.  On the wing, this angle is the aerodynamic angle of the wing.  Generally speaking, the angle of attack is not equal to the aerodynamic angle.  But there is an internal connection between them.

Is my idea correct?
————-

Comment: suggest you 1) reduce the number of questions in this to 1, and 2) move it to the aviation stack exchange.

Comment: @nielsnielsen How to transfer it directly?

Comment: do not know! it's called "migrating".

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica Sorry, it's a bit repetitive, but it has a deeper explanation.

Comment: @JMac Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please take a flying lesson, and please read [*this*](https://www.av8n.com/how/) completely through.
Also, see whatever videos you can, such as by King Flight Schools, Rod Machado, Flight Chops, and many others.

Since I don't expect you to actually educate yourself on the subject, I will throw in a few points that others might read if you don't...

Drag consists of two parts:

1) *Parasitic drag* caused by friction with the wind. This can be minimized by making the airplane's shape as streamlined as possible. Such an airplane is called "slippery".

2) *Induced drag* caused by part of the lift vector pointing backward (as you intuited).
This can be minimized by maximizing the *aspect ratio*, the ratio between wing length and wing width. That's why gliders have long skinny wings.
This drag correlates with *wingtip vortices* that drain energy. Anything that reduces the strength of the wingtip vortices also reduces the induced drag.

Now, try to understand this: airplanes are not always flying level at constant altitude. Sometimes they are ascending, and just like a car climbing a hill, they need more power or thrust.
Sometimes they are descending, and just like a car descending a hill, they need less power, or more drag.

Every aircraft with particular weight, balance, and trim has a *favorite speed*, which the pilot can adjust (with the trim control).
If the pilot does nothing, the aircraft will travel at that speed up, down, or level depending on the amount of power being applied.
A paper airplane or glider descends at that speed because no power is being applied.

The angle at which it descends is determined by the ratio of lift (L) to drag (D), called the L/D ratio. This determines how far it can glide if there is no engine power.
In a typical small airplane like a Cessna 172 the L/D ratio is about 9 (at slow speed), meaning it can glide about 9 miles for every 1 mile of altitude lost.
For a typical jet transport like a Boeing 737, the L/D ratio is more like 25, so it can glide 25 miles while losing 1 mile of altitude.
This means for level flight the amount of thrust needed is about 1/25 of weight.
Notice one problem with being too slippery. *It's hard to come down.* That's why airplanes with a high L/D ratio need speed brakes or spoilers, which they deploy when descending or landing.

So why are jets so powerful? The answer is so they can climb at a steep angle when taking off.
Why do they need to climb at a steep angle? Safety, that's why. If they lose power for some reason, the higher they are, the farther they can glide, and find a good place to land.

Learn about flying. Lots of people would like to teach you.

Comment: The glider is not without power, the power of the glider can be the same gravity component as the speed direction.

Comment: So do you agree that thrust provides lift during horizontal flight?

Comment: @enbinzheng: Thrust offsets drag. Take the forward thrust, subtract the backward drag, and that makes a total horizontal force. If it's > 0 the plane ascends. If it's < 0 the plane descends. Stop trying to justify your idea and pay attention to what other people know.

Comment: When flying horizontally at a constant speed, the thrust is equal to the drag force, so lift is also generated.

Comment: When the thrust is greater than the drag, the aircraft also rises because the lift is increased.  The relationship between lift and thrust can be seen.